# PHP Keep the variable scope even after the page reload

Tags: php, html, variables, scope

The website generates the random number from 1 to 100 when accessing the **first page**(page1.php). And the user will guess the number.

The first page contains
 - a text box for accepting a
   number from the user, and a submit button.

The **second page**(page2.php) will be returned to the user if the guess number is too high or too low. And the page shows a message telling the user "Too High" or "Too Low". The page also contains
a button(retry button) that allows the user to go back to the first page(page1.php) to re-enter a new number
a button that allows the user to quit the game.

The **third page**(page3.php) is returned to the user if the guess is correct. The page displays "Correct", the random number, and the count of tries.

And I have this index.php which is heart for all the pages. And here is the code.

**index.php**

```
    <?php

$name = '';
$inputnumber = '';
$random = 33; //this is just an assumption to keep it simple
$message = '';
$guesscount = '';
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}

if ($action === 'guess') {
    $guesscount = $_POST['$guesscount'];
    $inputnumber = $_POST['$inputnumber'];
    if ($inputnumber == $random) {
        $message = "Correct!";
        include 'page3.php';
    }
    if ($inputnumber > $random) {
        $message = "Too High";
        include 'page2.php';
    }
    if ($inputnumber < $random) {
        $message = "Too Low";
        include 'page2.php';
    }
}

if ($action === 'retry') {
    include 'page1.php';
}
```

**page1.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Number Guess</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Number Guess</h1>
        <form name="myForm" action="index.php" method="post" >
            Number Guess: <input type="text" name="$inputnumber" value="<?php if(isset($inputnumber)==1){
echo $inputnumber;}else echo ""; ?>" /><br>

            <input type="submit" name="action" value="guess" />
            <hr>
            Guess Count: <?php echo $guesscount; ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Number Guess</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Number Guess</h1>
        <form name="myForm" action="index.php" method="post" >
            Message: <?php echo $message; ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="$guesscount" value="<?php echo $guesscount;?>"/><br>
           <input type="submit" name="action" value="retry" />

            <hr>
           Guess Count: <?php echo $guesscount;?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page3.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Number Guess</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Number Guess</h1>
        <form name="myForm" action="index.php" method="post" >
            Message: <?php echo $message; ?>
            Number of Tries: <?php echo $guesscount; ?>
           <input type="submit" name="action" value="ok" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

page1.php is the page to load first.

Challenge I have faced is, I couldn't keep the $guesscount stable always. It keeps resetting on me. I have tried session but couldn't resolve it.Please help resolving it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either session, cookie or database ;) - session should work just fine why it wasn't working for you ?

Comment: A session should work, not sure why it wouldn't. Other options could be that you pass the variable along via POST or GET (encode it so they don't know the number) or maybe even use a cookie.

Comment: A session variable is the way to go here.  Not sure why session variables aren't working for you, but you show no code trying to use them, so we can't help you with code we don't see.  However, you could do most of this with just one PHP file, instead of 3, which would simplify things.

Comment: @SgtAJ I could do it with one page. But the problem occurs when I am using multiple pages. Session is working fine with one page. But I need to know how can I fix this one.

Comment: @MaciejCygan I could do it with one page. But the problem occurs when I am using multiple pages. Session is working fine with one page. But I need to know how can I fix this one.

Comment: Show us your code using session variables across multiple pages, please.  As long as you put `session_start();` at the top of all your pages, session variables should work fine.  Also, you're trying to use POST variables you didn't send, such as `$guesscount`.

Comment: I could do it using SESSION. Guys I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but my gut feeling tells me that the reason why the session is not working for you on other pages is because you do not initiate it ??

So what you have to do is:

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myVariable'] = 'myVariable';
?>
```

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$mySessionVar = $_SESSION['myVariable'];
var_dump($mySessionVar); // <- this should print myVariable
?>
```

You may get an error saying that $_SESSION is null or not set and to prevent that you can just enclose $_SESSION inside and isset method

```
if(isset($_SESSION['myVariable']) && $_SESSION['myVariable'] != null) {
  $mySessionVar = $_SESSION['myVariable'[;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have initialized it in index.php but I didn't include session variable in other pages. Maybe that would work. I will try and let you know.

Comment: @user3423927 it has to ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help Cygan. I could do it using SESSIONS. Your suggestion really helped me.

Comment: @user3423927 Well if this helped you please accept my answer as the right answer :)